# Node.js "node" command won't work, just exits

Tags: node.js

I have a question. A few months ago, I found a problem in Node.js: all of a sudden, when I tried to execute the "node" command, nothing would happen, it just exits. (Yes, after the node command i DID put a .js file). Due to this problem, I couldn't be able to code Discord bots (I'm coding with discord.js) for a long while. And I still have this problem, and I want to find out **why** there's this problem. I'll put a screenshot. (Name censored):
[node.js problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRsLv.png)

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on("message", async (message) => {
  console.log("\r\nUser sent message: \"" + message.content + "\", from server \"" + message.guild.name + "\" from user " + message.member.user.username + " prepared to be sent at exactly " + message.mentions._client.readyAt + ".\r\n");

if(message.content = "Ping") {
  message.channel.send("Pong!");
}
bot.login("My bot token");

});
```

This is my code.

Comment: please post some code

Comment: What happens when you type `node` by itself? Do you enter the node REPL?

Comment: Yes, I enter the code REPL.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code. You just aren't doing anything with it. check out a more full example like here https://gist.github.com/eslachance/3349734a98d30011bb202f47342601d3

Answer (score 0):

The problem on your code is that you're trying to login after you receive a message. That won't work because you need to login and then you'll receive the messages.
This should work:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on("message", async (message) => {
  console.log("\r\nUser sent message: \"" + message.content + "\", from server \"" + message.guild.name + "\" from user " + message.member.user.username + " prepared to be sent at exactly " + message.mentions._client.readyAt + ".\r\n");

  if(message.content = "Ping") {
     message.channel.send("Pong!");
  }

});

bot.login("My bot token");
```